# ActionScript 3 If Else for Button Click

Tags: if-statement, actionscript-3, button

I'm complete noob about this.

So, in a scene, there is an answer choice button A or B and a "next" button. In short, if we want to go to the next frame (click the "next" button), we have to click on one of the answer options first. However, I am confused about how to make the code.
Can you guys help me? (sorry for my bad english)

```
errorframe5.visible = false;

var pressed = "yes";

nextbutton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, nextframe6);
function nextframe6(event:MouseEvent):void
{
if(button_a == "no" && button_b == "no")
{
    errorframe5.visible = true;
}
else
{
    gotoAndStop(7, "Material");
}   
}
```

Comment: I think you need to use **RadioButtonGroup** from the standard Flash components, it automatically handles selecting one option out of many. Scroll down for the example and keep in mind that you actually have to add components to your project Library in order for the code to work: https://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/fl/controls/RadioButtonGroup.html

Answer (score 0):

I think you need code like that:

```
nextbutton.enabled = false;
buttonA.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, buttonAPressed);
buttonB.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, buttonBPressed);
function buttonAPressed (MouseEvent){
trace("your answer is correct");
nextbutton.enabled = true;
buttonA.enabled= false;
buttonB.enabled = false;
}
function buttonBPressed (MouseEvent){
trace("your answer is wrong");
nextbutton.enabled = true;
buttonA.enabled= false;
buttonB.enabled = false;
}
```